# Java Timer isRunning() check failed

Tags: java, timer

My logic is:

1. When new data coming, check if timer is running
2. If running, do nothing
3. If not running, trigger timer to schedule a TimerTask to be executed after 3000ms
4. When TimerTask starts to run, set timer.isRunning to false

My problem:

This mechanism doesn't work. The timer was triggered several times within 1s. However, timer should not be triggered more frequently than once every 3s.

In my timer there is a boolean isRunning. When timer starts, set isRunning=true. It's set back to false when TimerTask is triggered.

```
public class DBconnectDelayTimer extends Timer {

    /**
     *  Indicates if the Timer is running
     */
    private boolean isRunning;

    public DBconnectDelayTimer() {
        super();
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay) {
        isRunning = true;
        super.schedule(task, delay);
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public void resetTimer() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

I use timer in this way:

```
for(Item item : items) {
    if(item.getUID.equals(uid)) {
        itemExist = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!itemExist) {
    items.add(item);
    runTimer();
}
```

runTimer method is as below:

```
private void runTimer() {
    if (!mTimer.isRunning()) {
        mTimer.schedule(getTimerTask(), 3000);
        Log.d("WTF", "Run Timer");
    }
}
```

mTimer.schedule() should have set isRunning to true and timer shouldn't schedule another TimerTask before the previous TimerTask running.

```
private TimerTask getTimerTask() {
    final Fragment hostFragment = this;
    Log.d("WTF", hostFragment.getClass().toString());

    return new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**
             *  Reset Timer so it can be scheduled for next round of execution
             */
            mTimer.resetTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it failed. The Log shows that:

```
11-30 18:28:25.002 26842-27081/com.nethom.itemmanager D/WTF: Run Timer
11-30 18:28:25.003 26842-27085/com.nethom.itemmanager D/WTF: Run Timer
11-30 18:28:25.003 26842-27086/com.nethom.itemmanager D/WTF: Run Timer
11-30 18:28:25.003 26842-27083/com.nethom.itemmanager D/WTF: Run Timer
11-30 18:28:25.003 26842-27082/com.nethom.itemmanager D/WTF: Run Timer
11-30 18:28:25.003 26842-27084/com.nethom.itemmanager D/WTF: Run Timer
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: what are `mTimer` and `dBconnectDelayTimer` ?

Comment: Did you try put the boolean variable `volatile` so that other threads have visibility of changes

Comment: @nachokk yes I tried, didn't work.

Comment: @jhamon DBconnectDelayTimer mTimer

Comment: If you want to stop the timer just used `dBconnectDelayTimer.cancel()`, `dBconnectDelayTimer.resetTimer();` just barely set up the *isRunning* to false. The *false* part is not really connected to the logic that will stop a timer.

Comment: @JanKaufmann I don't want to stop timer. I just don't want the timer to schedule another task before the previous one gets running. Each task the timer schedule has 3000ms delay